# How Can I Run A Batch File (.Bat) Using SQL Triggers

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows, batch-file, triggers

I am trying to run a .bat file stored in a D:\ drive using `SQL triggers`. 
when some operation occurs in a table this trigger need to be fired and Batch file has to be executed.
for that i have created a sample trigger.

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[TestBatch] ON [dbo].[RawMaterial] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @PassedVariable VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)
begin
--SET @PassedVariable = 'SqlAuthority.com'
SET @CMDSQL = 'D:\AutoServer.bat'-- + @PassedVariable
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell @CMDSQL
end
```

but i am not getting a proper output. when i run the above script it is giving some error message saying.

> "The device is not ready.  NULL"

I would request all to give me a solution for my above issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do it. There are many things that can go wrong with running a batch file using xp_cmdshell, and when they go wrong, your trigger will hold up / rollback / error your database change. You should instead implement a queuing system. You trigger writes to a queue table, and a seperate process takes records off this queue and runs the batch file. In this way you can seperate your database changes from your batch file.

Comment: With regards to your error: Are you sure all of the drives you expect are really there? Do you have a D drive on your SQL Server? Remember xp_cmdshell runs things on the SQL Server, not on the client, and it (generally) runs them as the SQL Server service

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to run a bat file on a table trigger it can be very  problematic depending on what your bat file is doing and how much it has to do. Also how often the table trigger is fired can also exacerbate the problem too.
Better to store tables affected trigger records to another seperate table with say a processed flag and run bat file periodically thru a SQL scheduled job that once record is processed through the bat file will flip the processed flag to true.